# Limit HomePage via parent_page_types to be only available as direct child of root

Tags: wagtail

I use `parent_page_types` and `subpage_types` happily all around my Page-models.

But I'm stuck at allowing my `class HomePage(Page)` only as a direct child at root level.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Answer**: If you are landing here on 2023 like me there is an easier way to do this now. Just add `max_count` prop to your model like so:

```py
class HomePage(Page):
    #...

    max_count = 1
```

Answer (score 30):

Try this:

```
parent_page_types = ['wagtailcore.Page']
```

also, for completeness, to allow only one instance of a Homepage, add this classmethod to your `HomePage`:

```
@classmethod
def can_create_at(cls, parent):
    # You can only create one of these!
    return super(HomePage, cls).can_create_at(parent) \
        and not cls.objects.exists()
```

Comment: Wow! That was fast - and that's exactly what I was looking for, thank you.

Comment: Works for Wagtail 2 and in Django 2.

Comment: I logged in specially to give you a thumbs up (Y)

Comment: The second part of @serafim answer - allow only one instance of a page model - now seems to be part of wagtails page methods/properties via ``max_count`` (and that should work even on multisite setups): http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.4/reference/pages/model_reference.html#wagtail.core.models.Page.max_count

Comment: And now in v2.5 the more useful property `max_count_per_parent` exists. http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.5/reference/pages/model_reference.html#wagtail.core.models.Page.max_count_per_parent

Answer (score 2):

First of all, thumbs up for @Serafeim answer, but I will post my answer for people searching for issue similar to mine.

I wanted to achieve the same thing but for a specifi parent in multi-site mode. Meaning I wanted to have multiple site "HomePage" but each "HomePage" can only include one "SearchIndexPage". So the above answer would be modified to

```
    @classmethod
    def can_create_at(cls, parent):
        # You can only create one of these!
        return super(SearchIndexPage, cls).can_create_at(parent) \
               and parent.get_children().type(SearchIndexPage).count() == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

To allow for a page to be only created under the root page (for example for HomePage models) set the parent_page_type to ['wagtailcore.Page'].

max_count_per_parent
Controls the maximum number of pages of this type that can be created under any one parent page.

`class HomePage(Page): parent_page_types = ['wagtailcore.Page'] max_count_per_parent = 1`

[enter link description here](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/reference/pages/model_reference.html#wagtail.models.Page.parent_page_types)